# Get geo/reverse_geocode Twitter API not working

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-oauth, sttwitterapi

I couldn't use GET geo/reverse_geocode api. I am getting following error

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "message": "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource",
        "code": 220
    }]
}
```

I am using bearer token authorisation. Remaining APIs are working perfectly. Do I need to do any additional steps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That endpoint requires 3-legged user authentication.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/geo/places-near-location/api-reference/get-geo-reverse_geocode

> Requires authentication? -    Yes (user context only)